# How to auto tag up OCaml project?

Tags: ocaml

I would like to have a convenient way to manage the version of my OCaml project.

It is like

1. Current version is a dev version, like 1.0.0.dev
2. Then somehow I can use a tool to auto tag up the version to be 1.0.1
3. After tag up, there will be a new tag (1.0.1) in git
4. And it can be ready for opam publish

I am just wondering whether OCaml world has such a tool. Or is there anything I can use for this purpose?

Currently what I am doing is all manual.

Comment: this doesn't sound like too ocaml-specific, could be a general development tool?